# What does DPI QPainter use?

Tags: qt, qt5

What does DPI `QPainter` use? I figured out that `QPainter::drawText()` uses smaller DPI than my physical screen's DPI. Maybe somebody can point me in the code for it on [Woboq](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/)

Minimal example

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QScreen>


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QWidget w;
    QLabel * l1 = new QLabel( &w );
    QLabel * l2 = new QLabel( &w );
    QLabel * dpi = new QLabel( &w );

    QVBoxLayout * v = new QVBoxLayout( &w );
    QHBoxLayout * h = new QHBoxLayout;
    h->addWidget( l1 );
    h->addWidget( l2 );
    v->addLayout( h );
    v->addWidget( dpi );

    QFont f = w.font();
    f.setPointSize( 14 );

    l1->setText( QStringLiteral( "Text" ) );
    l1->setFont( f );

    qreal y = app.primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInchY();

    f.setPixelSize( ( y / 72.0 ) * 14.0 );
    l2->setText( QStringLiteral( "Text" ) );
    l2->setFont( f );

    dpi->setText( QString::fromLatin1( "Y DPI: %1" ).arg( QString::number( y ) ) );

    w.resize( 250, 200 );
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And what I see is...

[image]

Comment: `QPainter` probably uses the dpi of the underlying [`QPaintDevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html).  That being the case I think you need to edit your question to clarify the problem you are facing and provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Qt uses logical DPI for drawing text, that in my case is 96 DPI.

[image: DPI]

That is why `QFont::setPointSize()` leads to smaller font's size than it should be on my screen.